# Android attaching file from assets to email

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fileprovider

My app contains a PDF file in the assets folder. My goal is to create an email intent which opens an email with this PDF attached. It is working and the email opens and shows the PDF attached with the correct name and size. But when sending the email, the PDF is not received. The only thing that shows in logcat after sending the email is:

```
E/Gmail: gti:Cannot find size of file.
```

Which is odd because I can definitely see the attachment there with the correct size in the email draft.

Here is my code:

android-manfiest.xml:

```
    <provider
        android:name="[my.package.name].core.helpers.utils.AssetsProvider"
        android:authorities="[my.package.name].fileprovider2"
        android:exported="true"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true" />
```

AssetsProvider.kt

```
class AssetsProvider : ContentProvider() {

    override fun openAssetFile(uri: Uri, mode: String): AssetFileDescriptor? {
        val am = context!!.assets
        val fileName = uri.lastPathSegment!!
        var afd: AssetFileDescriptor? = null
        try {
            afd = am.openFd(fileName)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        // Confirms non null result
        Log.v("debug", "afd=" + (afd?.toString() ?: "null"))

        return afd
    }

    override fun onCreate(): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun insert(uri: Uri, values: ContentValues?): Uri? {
        return null
    }

    override fun query(
        uri: Uri,
        projection: Array<String>?,
        selection: String?,
        selectionArgs: Array<String>?,
        sortOrder: String?
    ): Cursor? {
        return null
    }

    override fun update(
        uri: Uri,
        values: ContentValues?,
        selection: String?,
        selectionArgs: Array<String>?
    ): Int {
        return 0
    }

    override fun delete(uri: Uri, selection: String?, selectionArgs: Array<String>?): Int {
        return 0
    }

    override fun getType(uri: Uri): String? {
        return null
        //return "application/pdf"
    }
}
```

And creating the `Intent` (java code):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    Uri assetUri = Uri.parse("content://[my.package.name].fileprovider2/[pdf_filename].pdf");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, assetUri);
    activity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Sending PDF..."), requestCode);
```

So like I said, it opens the gmail to compose a new email, the PDF attachment is there, correct filename and size, but when pressing send, the email goes through without any attachment and I get `E/Gmail: gti:Cannot find size of file.` in logcat when pressing send.

Why is the attachment not getting sent?

Comment: Have your `query()` support queries on the `OpenableColumns`. See [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/FINAL/ContentProvider/Files/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/cp/files/AbstractFileProvider.java) for example.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you that did it! Just needed to return the correct file length for that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some clients of your provider are going to want to use things like [`getName()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile#getName()) and [`length()` on `DocumentFile`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile#length()). In this case, it would appear that the client is trying to get the length

Those functions, in turn, will use a `ContentResolver` to `query()` your provider for [the `OpenableColumns`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/OpenableColumns). Your mission — should you choose to accept it — will be to have your `query()` function in your provider return a `Cursor` with values for the `DISPLAY_NAME` and/or `SIZE` columns. A `MatrixCursor` is an easy (if clunky) solution to implementing this easy (if clunky) API.

Canned providers, like `FileProvider`, handle this for you. Since you're rolling your own provider, you need to handle this yourself.

Comment: Confirming this answered my question thanks. Should `FileProvider` work if the file is in assets? I'm under the assumption I needed to roll my own `ContentProvider` for assets.

Comment: @jefferson: `FileProvider` does not handle assets. FWIW, [my `StreamProvider` does](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider). Yours should be fine, though I'd return a real MIME type from `getType()`, and `!!` makes me nervous when applied to input from outside parties. Also, you may want to think about whether you really want to export this provider -- if you add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to your `Intent`, you would not need to export the provider, and that incrementally improves security.